# Finger Position on Touchpad

Tags: python, touch, input-devices

I would like to get the (x,y) coordinate being touched on a Logitech Wireless Touchpad. I am programming in Python and hope to use the touchpad as an input device to drive a microscope stage. I am not really sure how to access the touch data; I have tried to access the device's USB connection through PySerial, but I cannot connect to the device through this module. This is a multitouch touchpad, and as such I am also interested in detecting multiple touches. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried [Kivy](http://kivy.org)? I'm not sure if it does what you want but it may well do. It's worth a try, at least.

Comment: I have not; I'll be sure to look into it and see what I can do.